# Field type Entity Reference as select list but based on value

Tags: views, entities

I want field with entity reference showed as select but based on value from the another field in the same form [radio button field] 
for example the entity reference field will list these values

-entity 1 
-entity 2 
-entity 3 
-entity 4

and the field radio button will hold countries like so:

-England 
-Germany

notice that the entities reference (Content Type) has field called country, so when i check the 
value "England" i want the field entity to be filtered based on England for ex:
-entity 1 & -entity 4
and same if i clicked Germany.

is that applicable in Drupal 7 even by Views module, or i have to do it custom !?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dynamic dependent fields](https://drupal.org/project/ddf) module.

Project page says:

> Makes field value or options depend on other field values when editing
>   entity.

Comment: Notice the filed is Entity Reference not Select with options

Answer (score 1):

i think it is done by [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)
see [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5z-GrHvl7s8) here

Comment: Hi @Praveen, please refrain from posting a one-link answer by describing the important steps from the tutorial in your answer. Thanks!